# Retrieving Data from database on quaterly basis condition But it should be based on current year data only

Tags: mysql

I had tried this code:

Its works also fine,but the issue is, if current month is feb and fire this query then it considers past 3 months from now and hence starts from past year i.e 2012 nov or dec say  i want only current year data,if it is feb now and i fire this query then it should only show jan and feb records.

```
   SELECT CROEmailId, 
(
SELECT COUNT(LeadId) 
FROM LeadStatus 
WHERE DATE(`LeadTime`)> DATE_SUB(now(), 
INTERVAL 3 MONTH
) 
AND Generated=1 and AssignedTo=a.CROEmailId) 
AS 'NEW LEAD',(
SELECT COUNT(LeadId) 
FROM LeadHistory 
WHERE DATE(UpdatedAt)> DATE_SUB(now(), 
INTERVAL 3 MONTH
) AND AssignedTo=a.CROEmailId) 
AS 'Lead Updated',
(
SELECT SUM(TotalEmails)
FROM MailJobs 
WHERE DATE(CompletedAt)> DATE_SUB(now(), 
INTERVAL 3 MONTH
) 
AND MailFrom=a.CROEmailId) 
AS 'Email Uploaded',
(
SELECT SUM(TotalSent) 
FROM MailJobs 
WHERE DATE(CompletedAt)> DATE_SUB(now(), 
INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
AND MailFrom=a.CROEmailId
) 
AS 'Email Sent',
(
SELECT SUM(NetTotal) 
FROM Invoice 
WHERE Status='PAID' 
AND DATE(CreatedAt)> DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
AND CROEmailId=a.CROEmailId) 
AS 'Payment Today' FROM CustomersManager a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change

```
DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

to

```
IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) < 4, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01'), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

in all subqueries.

```
SELECT CROEmailId, 
       (SELECT COUNT(LeadId) 
          FROM LeadStatus 
         WHERE DATE(`LeadTime`)> IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) < 4, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01'), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
           AND Generated=1 
           AND AssignedTo=a.CROEmailId) AS 'NEW LEAD',
       (SELECT COUNT(LeadId) 
          FROM LeadHistory 
         WHERE DATE(UpdatedAt)> IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) < 4, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01'), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
           AND AssignedTo=a.CROEmailId) AS 'Lead Updated',
       (SELECT SUM(TotalEmails)
          from MailJobs 
         WHERE DATE(CompletedAt)> IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) < 4, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01'), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
           AND MailFrom=a.CROEmailId) AS 'Email Uploaded',
       (SELECT SUM(TotalSent) 
          FROM MailJobs 
         WHERE DATE(CompletedAt)> IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) < 4, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01'), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
           AND MailFrom=a.CROEmailId) AS 'Email Sent',
       (SELECT SUM(NetTotal) 
          FROM Invoice 
         WHERE Status='PAID' 
           AND DATE(CreatedAt)> IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) < 4, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01'), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
           AND CROEmailId=a.CROEmailId) AS 'Payment Today' 
  FROM CustomersManager a;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this solution actually i was thinking in some sort of this manner only thanks a lot...

But which one would be more optimized one sir??

Answer (score 0):

use this in your query to find record filter by year

```
 YEAR( '20013-12-12' )
```

example,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR(DATE_FIELD) = 2013
```

Comment: Thnx a lot,how stupid of me...how my mind didnt think about that...

Thanks a lot...that worked as per my criteria..